# Open custom ContextMenuStrip on right-click

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am creating a TreeView with different types of TreeNodes, each with their own ContextMenuStrip menus.
I have a class `ElementTreeNode` which inherits from `TreeNode`. I want to add a `ElementContextMenu` which inherits from `ContextMenuStrip` menu to it which should open when right-clicking on the node.

My first approach was to simply add an instance of `ElementContextMenu` to the `ContextMenuStrip` property of my `ElementTreeNode`. But I added an EventHandler to `ElementTreeNode` which I can not access in this way. Probably because the property downcasts to `ContextMenuStrip` and thus loses the EventHandler which just exists in `ElementContextMenu`:

```
class ElementTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    public ElementTreeNode()
    {
        ContextMenuStrip = new ElementContextMenu();
    }
}
```

My second idea was to add a property ElementContextMenu to the class and then let the right-click event open this menu instead of the ContextMenuStrip property:

```
class ElementTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    public ElementContextMenu ElementContextMenu;

    public ElementTreeNode()
    {
        ElementContextMenu = new ElementContextMenu();
    }
}
```

So my question is:
**How can I open the `ElementContextMenu` property instead of the `ContextMenuStrip` when I right-click the node?**
Is there a way to change this behavoir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your `ElementTreeNode` class like this:

```
class ElementTreeNode : TreeNode
{    

  public ElementTreeNode()
  {
    ElementContextMenu = new ElementContextMenu();
  }

  public ElementContextMenu ElementContextMenu
  {
    get { 
      return ContextMenuStrip as ElementContextMenu; 
    }
    private set { 
      ContextMenuStrip = value; 
    }
  }
}
```

Now whenever you need to add an EventHandler or access properties which only exist in `ElementContextMenu` class use the `ElementContextMenu` property.

The *old* `ContextMenuStrip` property will still behave the same way (open a context menu when you right-click the node), but it will open your instance of `ElementContextMenu` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This solution comes close to what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Just show the `ContextMenu` manually and don't assign the `TreeView`'s context menu. E.g.

```
        TreeView tv = new TreeView() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        tv.Nodes.Add(new ElementTreeNode { Text = "Node 1" });
        tv.Nodes.Add(new ElementTreeNode { Text = "Node 2" });
        tv.MouseDown += (o, e) => {
            TreeNode n = tv.GetNodeAt(e.Location);
            tv.SelectedNode = n; // known bug, force selected node
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
                if (n is ElementTreeNode) {
                    var n2 = (ElementTreeNode) n;
                    n2.ElementContextMenu.Show(tv, e.Location);
                }
            }
        };
```